# Select Total and If Read

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following tables:

Book

```
Id Title 
1  Test
```

BookPage (BookId corresponds to Id from Book table)

```
Id BookId Page
1  1      1
1  1      2
```

BookUserPage (BookPageId corresponds to Id from BookPage table)

```
UserId BookPageId
1      1
2      2
3      1
```

My select query is as follows:

```
SELECT B.[Id], B.[Title], BP.[Id], BP.[BookId], BP.[Page], COUNT(BUP.[BookpageId]) AS Total
FROM [Book] B
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [BookPage] BP ON BP.[BookId] = B.[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [BookUserPage] BUP ON BUP.[BookPageId] = BP.[Id]
WHERE B.[Id] = 1
GROUP BY B.[Id], B.[Title], BP.[Id], BP.[BookId], BP.[Page]
```

The result I get is the following:

```
Id, Title, Id, BookId, Page, Total
1   Test   1,  1,      1,    2
1   Test   2,  1,      1,    1
```

I'm trying to modify the query so that it will also tell me which of the 2 pages were read by the user.

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT B.[Id], B.[Title], BP.[Id], BP.[BookId], BP.[Page], COUNT(BUP.[BookpageId]) AS Total,
CASE WHEN EXISTS (
    SELECT BUP2.[UserId] 
    FROM [PollUserAnswer] BUP2
    WHERE BUP2.[UserId] = '98ad813b-cd0e-4a63-b40a-e09ee84f4b96')
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END AS Voted
FROM [Book] B
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [BookPage] BP ON BP.[BookId] = B.[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [BookUserPage] BUP ON BUP.[BookPageId] = BP.[Id]
WHERE B.[Id] = 1
GROUP BY B.[Id], B.[Title], BP.[Id], BP.[BookId], BP.[Page]
```

But the above puts a 1 on both rows of my result. I have also tried adding in the Case statement a condition:

```
AND BUP2.[BookPageId] = BUP.[PageId]
```

But that can't work due to group by and i can't list it in the group by as its a subquery.

My Desired Output for user 1 and 3 is this:

```
Id, Title, Id, BookId, Page, Total, Read
1   Test   1,  1,      1,    2,     1
1   Test   2,  1,      1,    1,     0
```

My Desired Output for user 2 is this:

```
Id, Title, Id, BookId, Page, Total, Read
1   Test   1,  1,      1,    2,     0
1   Test   2,  1,      1,    1,     1
```

Note: Please ignore the fact that there are 2 Id columns in the query output.

Comment: Is "ID" in Book is same as "ID" in BookPage? Or "BookID" is "ID" in Book?

Comment: @NirmalSubedi BookPage table has a column BookId which corresponds to Id from Book table.

Comment: Shouldn't `BookUserPage` also have a column which refers to which book?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen At the moment it does not, I haven't seen a need for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would join to separate subquery to find the total number of users who read a given page.  Then, you only need to tag on another left join to `BookUserPage` to generate the `Read` column:

```
SELECT b.Id, b.Title, bp.Id, bp.BookId, bp.Page, bup1.total,
    CASE WHEN bup2.UserId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS [Read]
FROM Book b
LEFT JOIN BookPage bp
    ON bp.BookId = b.Id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT BookPageId, COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM BookUserPage
    GROUP BY BookPageId
) bup1
    ON bup1.BookPageId = bp.Id
LEFT JOIN BookUserPage bup2
    ON bup2.BookPageId = bp.Id AND bup2.UserId = 1
WHERE b.Id = 1;
```

### Demo

This is not generating the results you expect, but it seems logically correct given your actual sample data and the join logic.